# Hyper-v Manager is not availbale in RDP of window Azure portal

Tags: azure

I would like to create vhd file for Machine which i have connected from Auzre portal remotely.
I had gone through VM roles in window azure and came to point that first i required to take image of machine and for that requires Hyper-v Manager but it is also available on Window server 2008 R2 , so i have configured os of my deployment to R2 but still there is no option of Hyper-v Manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I completely understand your question, but I *think* you're asking about managing your VHDs in Windows Azure with Hyper-V running in Windows Azure. Is that correct?

In Windows Azure, there's no Hyper-V Manager that you access. You only use Hyper-V locally, on a local Windows 2008 server, to create your VHDs. These VHDs are then uploaded to Windows Azure.

I suggest you download the [Windows Azure Platform Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8396) and run through the Virtual Machine Role lab, as it shows all the necessary steps. You'll see that all Hyper-V access is done on-premise, not in Windows Azure. Once the vhd is created:

- Mount a drive containing the Windows Azure extensions, and install those to your vhd.
- Run the **csupload** command line tool (part of the Windows Azure SDK) to upload your vhd to your Windows Azure account.
- Create a new Windows Azure project in Visual Studio, adding a VM Role, configuring it to look into your subscription and letting you select the vhd you just uploaded.
- Create a new Hosted Service via the portal, then uploading the newly-created Windows Azure deployment package.

There are more details to each of those steps, which are all spelled out in great detail in the VM Role lab mentioned above.